# How do I linearize a quadratic problem about graph theory?

Tags: python, optimization, undirected-graph, linearization

I need to solve a maxcut problem of a graph having 4 nodes and 5 edges, but I have to do it both with a quadratic solution and a linear one. I need to transform the quadratic maxcut problem to the linear one by adding some constraints but I have no idea how to do it.

This is the version I found of the quadratic one:

```
import numpy as np

from qiskit_optimization import QuadraticProgram
from qiskit_optimization.algorithms import MinimumEigenOptimizer

from qiskit import BasicAer
from qiskit.algorithms import QAOA
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SPSA

# Generate a graph of 4 nodes
n = 4
graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_nodes_from(np.arange(0, n, 1))
elist = [(0, 1, 1.0), (0, 2, 1.0), (0, 3, 1.0), (1, 2, 1.0), (2, 3, 1.0)]
graph.add_weighted_edges_from(elist)

# Compute the weight matrix from the graph
w = nx.adjacency_matrix(graph)
print(w)

# Formulate the problem as quadratic program
problem = QuadraticProgram()
_ = [problem.binary_var('x{}'.format(i)) for i in range(n)] # create n binary variables
linear = w.dot(np.ones(n))
quadratic = -w
problem.maximize(linear=linear, quadratic=quadratic)
print(problem.export_as_lp_string())
```

Now I should formulate the problem as linear, by adding the following constraints: (link of the image below)

<(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu00W.jpg)>

Thanks in advance for helping